# How to redirect viewer's attention to a certain card among similar cards?

Tags: website-design, layout, interface, user-engagement, motivation

I am a product designer but I also work on illustrations and web designs on the side. On my portfolio, I would like to motivate viewers to click the first card (UX/UI card) rather than the other two.

I was thinking that since most people start reading from left (Z and F pattern), it is best to put it first.

But I also noticed, SaaS products usually list their most sought plan in the middle (Basic, Pro, Enterprise).

I have been trying a lot with different colours, patterns etc on the first card but failing to make it motivating enough to be clicked first. The challenge is that the layout and size of the card needs to be similar to the other two because of 2 reasons:

1. I don't want to hide the other two below the viewport.
2. The image placeholders you noticed are from a same series. So it makes sense to have those 3 cards side by side.

Any idea how I can make this UX/UI card stand out?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The same thing happens with pricing plans, which are just cards with content. Here are some examples where you can get ideas or combine them:

#### Size Contrast

[image: Pricing Plan 1]

#### Adding a distinctive graphic element

[image: Adding a graphic element]

#### Drop Shadow

[image: Pricing plan 3]

<sub>*Image source [dribbble.com](https://dribbble.com/shots/12268448-TheDifference-Onboarding-Pricing)*</sub>

#### Outline

[image: Pricing plan 4]

<sub>*Image source [dribbble.com](https://dribbble.com/shots/10444308-Pricing-Plans)*</sub>

#### Color contrast

[image: Pricing plan 5]

<sub>*Image source [wpdatatables.com](https://wpdatatables.com/pricing-table-examples/#)*</sub>

#### Active CTA

[image: Pricing plan 6]

<sub>*Image source [uidesigndaily.com](https://www.uidesigndaily.com/posts/sketch-pricing-table-price-day-988)*</sub>

#### Position Contrast

[image: Pricing plan 7]

<sub>*Image source [shutterstock.com](https://www.shutterstock.com/es/image-vector/ui-ux-price-table-design-template-1366412579)*</sub>

#### Positive/Negative

The image in the question has the color as a decorative element. For the contrast to be truly effective, it is much better to use positive/negative either in black and white or color and white.

[image]

Comment: I have tried the colour contrast (as you can see) and the graphic element option in another iteration. The graphic element looked like I am trying to offer something on sale. Maybe I need to make better badges. I am thinking to combine the drop shadow, outline and colour contrast option. I really wanted to do the CTA option but buttons are not part of the cards' original design. The whole card is clickable. More clickable area.

Comment: Answer updated.-

Answer (score 1):

You've already given the first card a different color, which makes it unique and out standing from the other ones. To give it even more attention I'd suggest you adding an animation to the card or an element/badge inside the card. For example an outline of the card (perhaps an animated outline would draw even more attention, a video example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjeoJu6agQk&ab_channel=FlorinPop)). My other suggestion would be to add CTA's to the cards ("Read more" button might fit in good) and use a different style on the first cards' CTA. Also please make sure to maintain a good contrast between card's background and text color and always check it on [Webaim](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) :)

To be honest, these suggestions aren't very accessibility friendly, and I feel like this question is a little bit of opinion based and there are no right-wrong answers...